# Any API in Blackberry to make a call and send data?

Tags: blackberry, gsm

Any API in blackberry to make a call and send data. I want to dial a number and send some data using GSM data(not GPRS). Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a StreamConnection

```
String url = "socket://" + host + ":" + port
                                        + (checked ? "":";deviceside=true");
StreamConnection connection =  (StreamConnection) Connector.open(url,
                                        Connector.READ_WRITE, true);
```

deviceside=false indicates that the blackberry will connect to the Internet with a proxy in your MDS

deviceside=true open a direct TCP connection

Answer (score 0):

You can send and receive data by SMS:

[BlackBerry KB - What Is - Different ways to send SMS messages](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/What_is_-_Different_ways_to_send_SMS_messages.html?nodeid=1588663&vernum=0)
[BlackBerry KB - What Is - Different ways to listen for SMS messages](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/What_Is_-_Different_ways_to_listen_for_SMS_messages.html?nodeid=1357551&vernum=0)
[BlackBerry KB - How To - Use SMS to notify an application](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/How_To_-_Use_SMS_to_notify_an_application.html?nodeid=1266974&vernum=0)

If you want, you can hook call and send SMS automatically:
[BlackBerry KB - How To - Implement the PhoneListener interface](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800536/How_To_-_Implement_the_PhoneListener_interface.html?nodeid=817212&vernum=0)

Comment: Actually, I don't want to send as SMS as my data size is quite high(around 32K). Also this has to be not sent in single packet, but series of handshakes and parts of data.

Comment: in other words can I use the Blackberry as a GSM modem from an application running on the blackberry itself. I know it's possible to use the blackberry as a GSM modem from a PC.